# How to install windows 8 on another hard drive when windows 8 came preinstalled on laptop?

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I bought a laptop and now I received an hard drive failure message. It still works for now but I think it wont last very long. What do I have to do in order to install windows 8 on another hard drive since I don't have any install disk ?

Comment: Just download the .iso from Microsoft, all 8.1 users are eligible

Answer (score 0):

If you have the hard drive you want to transfer to, you can use a bootable disk cloning software, such as [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), to copy your internal drive to the external one. You will need a USB to SATA adapter, which I will link to below.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-2-0-to-IDE-SATA-S-ATA-2-5-3-5-Hard-Drive-HD-HDD-Converter-Adapter-Cable-New-/331250999094?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d20191f36

Answer (score -1):

You can download the original ISOS from here:

[ISOS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media)

When the installation prompted, type your original Windows 8 serial key from your old laptop .

Comment: your link downloads an exe that claims to be a windows 8 installer and asks to be on the computer I want to install windows on, are you sure it will download the iso so I can burn it into a bootable disk ? Beside I don't have a serial key in the back of my laptop I think they removed it in all windows 8 laptops

Comment: In that case, key could be in the UEFI Firmware or BIOS, you can use this third party program: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html.

Depending on the OEM version of Windows that you are running, you will sometimes have an issue using the OEM key with a retail version of Windows, but you can always install and then call Microsoft and get them to straighten it out and allow your copy to activate. The most important thing is that you have a valid license key.

Comment: Edited the url: Create media dvd or usb from a ISO: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Comment: Windows 8 OEM system no longer have a product key on a such a sticker. The key is embedded o the UEFI.

Comment: Yeah, as i said in the 2nd comment.